# Why do I get `egrep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied` when running this awk command?

Tags: sudo

Does anyone know why this command:

```
sudo awk -v LIMIT=50000 -F: '($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | tee - |egrep -f - /etc/shadow > /home/bulgarini/server_transfer/shadow.sync
```

gives the message

```
egrep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

See the permisions of `/etc/shadow` file:

```
ls -l /etc/shadow
```

The output is something like:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1530 apr 10 08:47 /etc/shadow
```

So, only root and those users from shadow group have permissions to read that file. So, in conclusion, you need to run that command as root.

If you think that you run that compound command as root because you put `sudo` in front of it, you are wrong - in this case `sudo` affects only the `awk` command and nothing else after the pipe (`|`). I sugest you the following:

```
sudo -i
awk -v LIMIT=50000 -F: '($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | tee - |egrep -f - /etc/shadow > /home/bulgarini/server_transfer/shadow.sync
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sudo awk -v LIMIT=50000 -F: '($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | tee - |sudo egrep -f - /etc/shadow > /home/bulgarini/server_transfer/shadow.sync`

or

`sudo awk -v LIMIT=50000 -F: '($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534) {print $1}' /etc/passwd | tee - | sudo egrep -f - /etc/shadow > /home/bulgarini/server_transfer/shadow.sync`

You need sudo privileges to run egrep and after a | is considered a new command so it needs a sudo as well